# Delphi - compiler continue on error

Tags: delphi, delphi-2006

Is there any possibility to make compiler continue when errors are encountered during the compilation an application in D2006? I want to know how many errors it finds on an application.

Comment: Ask your co-worker how one would write a parser that can continue from any error, including extra or missing begin, extra or missing end statement, unterminated string constants, etc. :-)

Comment: you know, there are people who believe that they can do anything...and they are Guru in development...and the proclaim themselves bosses, etc, etc...so it's useless

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No there is not. The problem is that once the compiler can't compile one unit, it's in no position to compile the other ones that, more than likely, depend on the unit that could not be compiled. This is because compilation of a unit requires a .dcu file for all of the used units.

Comment: That's what I knew, that is not possible...discussion with coworker done :) thank you